String is palindrome
I want to know why the function is not returning.
I want to check that a string is a palindrome or not by only checking alphabets.
Code
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string s)
{
    int strSize = s.size();
    if (strSize == 1 || strSize == 0)
    {
        cout << " i am gone bro" << endl;
        return true;
    }

    char first = (char)tolower(s[0]);
    char last = (char)tolower(s[strSize - 1]);

    if (!(first >= 'a' && first <= 'z'))
    {
        cout << "after trim first -> " << s.substr(1, strSize - 1) << endl;
        isPalindrome(s.substr(1, strSize - 1));
    }

    if (!(last >= 'a' && last <= 'z'))
    {
        cout << "after trim last -> " << s.substr(0, strSize - 2) << endl;
        isPalindrome(s.substr(0, strSize - 2));
    }

    if (first == last)
    {
        cout << "euqual " << first << endl
             << (s.substr(1, strSize - 2)) << endl;
        isPalindrome(s.substr(1, strSize - 2));
    }

    cout << " still running for " << s << " size " << strSize << endl;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    bool ans = isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama");
    cout << "ans = " << ans;
    return 0;
}

I want to check that a string is palindrome or not by only checking alphabets.

Does this answer your question? What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

There are a ton of questions on StackOverflow related to writing palindrome checks in C++

first >= 'a' && first <= 'z' -- Don't do this.  Use std::isalpha.

String is not a palindrome. bob is.

isalnum()?

In three places you forgot to return, it should be return isPalindrome(s.substr(1, strSize - 1)); etc. Returns don't happen automatically, you have to say return even when you are using recursion. For some reason beginners think the rules for recursive functions are different in some mysterious way, this is not true, if you want a function to return you need to say return, even if it's a recursive function.

Change bool isPalindrome(string s) to [[nodiscard]] bool isPalindrome(string s) and your compiler will start pointing out your mistakes.  You are discarding the value returned from calling that function.

I think the beginner thinks something like this, I make 10 recursive calls but as soon as I hit a single return statement that will be the return value for all 10 recursive calls. That is not true. If you make 10 recursive calls and you want all 10 recursive calls to contribute to the eventually returned value then you need to execute 10 return statements. In other words recursive function calls follow the same rules as non-recursive function calls.

You only need to check if first is alphabetic, because if first == last is true then last is alphabetic too.

You are overcomplicating things : https://onlinegdb.com/Sm2gogT_D

@PepijnKramer, The following assert fails,  assert(!is_palindrome("tac2cat"));

That much code is absolutely unnecessary.

I think OP needs to clearly state their requirements. Judging by the test input, capitalization has to be accounted for, and whitespace and non-alphas should be ignored. Is that everything?

@PepijnKramer It also fails on the provided test input.

"I want to know why the function is not returning." -- I want to know why you think the function is not returning. Which should not be hard to [edit] into your question. I see several places with diagnostic output added (good!), but what's missing is the result of running your function. If it's long (or never-ending) output, you don't have to include all of it, just the beginning up to the part where the output differs from your expectation. (Note: a shorter test string might make this easier.)

Example of a similar question with simpler and more focused example code: Recursion Function Return.

Instead of mucking up the isPalindrome() function, I opted to move all the required cleanup to a separate function. https://godbolt.org/z/3da6aEbeT

You have written isPalindrome() as a recursive function (ie, a function that calls itself), but you are not return'ing the value that each recursive call returns, eg:
if (!(first >= 'a' && first <= 'z'))
{
    ...
    return isPalindrome(s.substr(1, strSize - 1)); // <-- ADD RETURN!
}

Do the same for all of your recursive calls.

Generalizing this, if you're calling a function that returns a value and you ignore that value, you really need to ask yourself why you're ignoring it.

In C++17 and later, you can use [[nodiscard]] to issue a warning if a return value is ignored.
